# How to using Linq with Dataview?

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

I am learning linq to dataset from this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-dataview-object-linq-to-dataset
and I am having trouble when running this code, I do not understand why it doesn't work, however
The code works fine if I delete this line:

```
Where order1.Field(Of Integer)("Column2") = 1
```

my table have 4 columns corresponds to the name: Column1,2,3,4
Here is vbcode:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source='C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Danh STT.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
            ("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Author", "TestTable")
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        Dim orders As DataTable = DtSet.Tables(0)
        Dim query = From order1 In orders.AsEnumerable
                    Order By order1.Field(Of String)("Column1")
                    Where order1.Field(Of Integer)("Column2") = 1
                    Select order1
        Dim view As System.Data.DataView = New Data.DataView
        view = query.AsDataView()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can you explain for me please!
Thanks a lot.
Edit: [The error I received]

> {System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)" & vbCrLf & "   at Dataview.Form1._Closure$__._Lambda$__1-0(DataRow order1) in D:\2.0_VSTO_PROJECT\D_1_MY_PROJECT\1 EXCEL\.NET\1 Class .Net\LinqExample\Dataview\Dataview\Form1.vb:line 31" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1.b__16_0(DataRow row)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetLinqDataView>b__3(DataRow row)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataView.RowPredicateFilter.System.Data.IFilter.Invoke(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.Index.AcceptRecord(Int32 record, IFilter filter)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.Index.InitRecords(IFilter filter)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.Index..ctor(DataTable table, IndexField[] indexFields, Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force, Boolean fireEvent)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataView.SetIndex2(String newSort, DataViewRowState newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter, Boolean fireEvent)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataView..ctor(DataTable table, Predicate`1 predicate, Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState RowState)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1.GetLinqDataView()" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsDataView[T](EnumerableRowCollection`1 source)" & vbCrLf & "   at Dataview.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\2.0_VSTO_PROJECT\D_1_MY_PROJECT\1 EXCEL.NET\1 Class .Net\LinqExample\Dataview\Dataview\Form1.vb:line 36}

Comment: `Column2` doesn't contain `Integer` values. It's text or, classic, `Double`.

Comment: thank you. I have updated it

Comment: column 2 only includes values 1 and 2
I tried changing to double, integer, decimal but still didn't work

Comment: Check again the Excel Column. If the Column's Cell format is `General` or `Number` and you actually have numbers only in that Column (i.e., all *numbers* are correctly aligned to the right), the value type is `Double`. Also verify you're using the correct columns' names. Your code assumes that the first row of the Excel sheet contain the Columns' names. Otherwise, the Columns are named `F1`, `F2` etc. Or they're named after the values you have in the first row (since `HDR=Yes`)

Comment: If I convert column2 to text format it will work. But I don't want that. I think it requires something like:
Where order1.Field (Of Integer) ("Column2"). ToString = "2"
How to recognize datatype column2? it is column in excel and obviously i only enter 1 or 2 for it.

Comment: this's my file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvwbbF6HL04VhlAJACXf72_eSUjt?e=brBCSy

Comment: I think maybe because order1 specifies that the data is text.
whether it is so. Is it datarow and data must be consistent with the remaining columns?

Comment: You have formatted the cells in the Excel WorkSheet, so the range selection is extended to all cell that have the `Modified` flag on (setting the background color is enough to flag a cell as `Modified`, causing it to be part of the selected range). You need to specify the range manually, to avoid null values (or handle the possible null values instead). Change the SELECT command in `"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B1:E22]"`

Comment: hi Jimi. It's working. Thanks for saving me the time